# Highstock chart not displaying the dates correctly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, highcharts

I am trying to render a chart with data on a CSV file, however, when I open the chart the data is not exactly where I want it to be. I have been reading a lot some similar posts from here but when I go to examples provided in some answers the links are broken. How could I get this issue fixed?

My chart is located here: http://www.blucable.com/chart/index.php

My index.php looks like this:

```
<?php header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); ?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>ITS Dashboard Test Chart</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {

        var options = {
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Another Chart'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: []
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Units'
                }
            },
            rangeSelector : {
                                selected : 1
                            },
            series: []
        };

        $.get('table.csv', function(data) {
            // Split the lines
            var lines = data.split('\n');

            // Iterate over the lines and add categories or series
            $.each(lines, function(lineNo, line) {
                var items = line.split(',');

                // header line containes categories
                if (lineNo == 0) {
                    $.each(items, function(itemNo, item) {
                        if (itemNo > 0) options.xAxis.categories.push(item);
                    });
                }

                // the rest of the lines contain data with their name in the first 
                // position
                else {
                    var series = {
                        data: []
                    };
                    $.each(items, function(itemNo, item) {
                        if (itemNo == 0) {
                            series.name = item;
                        } else {
                            series.data.push(parseFloat(item));
                        }
                    });

                    options.series.push(series);

                }

            });

            // Create the chart
            var chart = new Highcharts.StockChart(options);
        }); 

    });

    </script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
    <div id="container" style="height: 500px; min-width: 500px"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

My CSV file looks like this:

```
Date,Open Tickets,Closed Tickets,Calls
2013-12-01,01,02,04
2013-11-01,06,07,09
2013-10-01,11,08,06
2013-09-01,16,09,10
```

Comment: Would you mind copying the relevant parts of your chart (e.g. the appropriate parts of your HTML and JavaScript) into your question? We like 'self contained' questions, since once you fix the page at that link, the question will not make sense for future readers. Thanks!

Comment: Oh I apologize, let me get it fixed asap!

Comment: Let us know how chart should look like, point us what is wrong with data position.

Comment: I was trying to show how many calls, open and closed tickets I get per day. For some reason that information is showing in different places and I can't get a way to display the date correctly in the timeline.

Comment: anybody knows anything?

Comment: We need any mockup of your chart.

Comment: I was able to solve this issue on my own, thanks!